# Laravel API Connecting to Client Database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, api, guzzle

I'm building 2 websites, one of them will be hosted on the server and the other one on localhost, both have their own database. The one on the server has API routes getting data from client and insert it to database. The function i'm trying to implement is that the one on localhost will be retrieving data from its own database, then call the API route of the other one on the server then inserting it to the server's database.

expected result :
Data from localhost database inserted into the server's database via API.

actual result :
The server is inserting the data back into the localhost database.

question :
Is there a way to force the server to insert the data to it's own database?

codes :
Localhost function

```
public function Sync (){
    $payload = t_worksheet::all()->toArray();
    $client = new Client();
    $res = $client->request('POST', 'http://localhost/cal-work/public/api/sync', ['form_params' => 
    ['payload' => $payload]]);
}
```

Server function

```
public function sync (Request $request) {
    $payload = $request->payload;
    foreach ($payload as $item) {
        $target = new t_worksheet_server;
        $target->name = $item['name'];
        $target->details = $item['details'];
        $target->approved_by = $item['approved_by'];
        $target->save();
    }

    return response()->json('success', 200);
}
```

Server API routes

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::post('/sync', 'SyncController@sync');
```

Local .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=ws-local
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=12345678
```

Server .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=db4free.net
DB_PORT=33060
DB_DATABASE=ws-server
DB_USERNAME=ckaryuusai
DB_PASSWORD=12345678
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked, i served the server project with `php artisan serve --port=8080` and changed the guzzle client to `localhost:8080`, it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

Check `.env` file in your root Laravel project folder, that should be the `Server`
That is where you usually specify the connection string for your DB.

If both of your websites use different DBs, and different connection initiations, they must use the respectively different hosts, and credentials to connect to the DB.

And for the Server to push data to the Client's DB, this sounds like a configuration issue..

Comment: both websites have different hosts and credentials, as for the config, i did check database.php, both of them are still in default configurations

Comment: by default `database.php` takes the connection details from your `.env` file.. there is no point checking that php file if it was not modified.. Can you add to your code the contents of `.env` for each website, only the one's that start with `DB_`

Comment: isn't `$res = $client->request('POST', 'http://localhost/cal-work/public/api/sync',` a POST towards your local host from your localhost? Shouldn't this URL be pointing to POST to the Server's URL ? That is why it posts to the local DB

Comment: i should've clarified that both projects are still in localhost